# Proving that the outer measure is translation invariant

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, then the translation $t+A$ is defined by the set $\{t+a:a \in A \}$

I am trying to prove that the outer measure of $t + A$ (denoted $|t+A|$) is the same as the outer measure $|A|$, where outer measure of an arbitrary set $X$ is defined as:

$ \large |X| = \inf \{\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k) : I_1,I_2, ... \text{are open intervals such that } X \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\}$

Where $l(I)$ is the length of the interval $I$. So we can write down the following for the set $t+A$:

$ \large |t + A| = \inf \{\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(t + I_k) : t+I_1,t+I_2, ... \text{are open intervals such that } t+A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty t+I_k\}$

However, $\sum_k l(t + I_k) =\sum_k( l(t) + l(I_k))= \sum_k l(I_k)$ , where $l(t) = 0$ because it is a single element of the real number line. Thus we have:

$ \large |t + A| = \inf \{\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k)\} = |A|$

I was under the impression that this completes the proof. However, it does not, and I don't understand why. Apparently, the steps I outlined above only prove that $|t+A| \leq |A|$ and then I still have to show that $|A|\leq |t+A|$ in order to complete the proof. I would appreciate it if someone could explain why $|t+A| \leq |A|$, since $|t+A|$ and $|A|$ appear to have the same definition.

Note:  what I am claiming is that the definition of $|t+A|$ and the definition of $|A|$ are exactly the same, and thus they must be equal. This is wrong apparently, but I don't understand why. The other Math Exchange posts (that people are claiming this is a duplicate of) tackle the problem from a different angle; they do not involve showing that the definitions are the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the Lebesgue Outer Measure is Translation Invariant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003597/show-that-the-lebesgue-outer-measure-is-translation-invariant)

Comment: It is a similar question, but not the same one. What I am claiming is that the $\text{definition}$ of $|t+A|$ and the $\text{definition}$ of $|A|$ are exactly the same, and thus they must be equal. This is wrong apparently, but I don't understand why.

Comment: The key to the whole thing is that the length of intervals remain the same when translated. There are several postings in MSE that discuss your problem.

Comment: My question is exactly this: what is wrong with the definition argument? I understand the other proofs on MSE - but what is wrong with my $\text{definitional}$ argument?

Answer (score 1):

If you have proven $|t+A|\le |A|$ for all $A$ and $t$, then choose $t \mapsto -t$, $A \mapsto t+A$ gives

$$|-t + (t+A)|\le |t+A|\Rightarrow |A|\le |t+A|.$$

**Remark** It is true that you proved only the inequality. Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary, by definition of $|A|$, there is an open cover $\{ I_i\}$ of $A$ by intervals so that
$$\sum_i l(I_i) \le |A| +\epsilon.$$
Note that $\{ t + I_i\}$ covers $t+A$. Thus

$$|t+A|\le \sum_i l(t+ I_i) = \sum_i l(I_i)\le |A| +\epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, you have $|t+A|\le |A|$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding the remark, I don't understand why $|t+A| \leq \sum_i|I_i|$ while $|A| = \sum_i|I_i|$. It seems that the two are defined exactly the same way - as the infimum along all coverings $I$. What am I missing?

Comment: It should be $l$ instead of $|\cdot|$. Is that okay now? @Sam

Comment: Oops, I also meant $\sum_il(I_i)$, but that doesn't change anything - I still don't understand why $|t+A| \leq \sum_i l(I_i)$ while  $|A| = \sum_i l(I_i)$. Shouldn't $A$ also be less than or equal to $\sum_i l(I_i)$? The implication is that $|t+A| \leq x$, $|A| \leq x \nRightarrow |t+A| \leq |A|$

Comment: @Sam I have clarified a bit.

Comment: Maybe the following question will make it clear where my issue is. Building on your edited answer, why can't we make the following argument: $\forall \epsilon > 0, |t+A| + \epsilon \geq \sum_i l(t+ I_i) = \sum_i l(I_i) = |A|$. Therefore, $|t+A| \geq |A|$

Comment: What is your $\{I_i\}$? In my answer, $\{I_i\}$ is found once $\epsilon$ is given. I don't have a $\{I_i\}$ which works for all $\epsilon$. @Sam

Comment: And yes, you can use similar method to show $|t+A|\ge |A|$. @Sam

Comment: $|t+A| = \inf \{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty l(t + I_k) : t+I_1,t+I_2, ... \text{are open intervals such that } t+A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty t+I_k\}$. This is the definition of the open measure on $|t+A|$, which chooses the set of intervals ${t+I_k}$ such that the sum of their lengths is the greatest lower bound of all possible ${t+I_k}$ that cover the set $t+A$